# Why doesn't my CSS work in IE10?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The following works in all major browsers, but not in IE10

### CSS:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 100px;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
.box:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: -6px;
    display: block;
    width: 108px;
    height: 108px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display:none;
}
.box:hover:after {
    display:block;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="box">hover me</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhWgA/)

Comment: I can't replicate it in emulated IE10? It looks identical to Chrome (latest windows).

Comment: Works fine for me in IE10. Are you perhaps running in compatibility mode?

Comment: Why not upgrade to the latest version of IE, as you would with other browsers? Seems to work fine, though.

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: You provide the code, but you don't say how its not working. What exactly is wrong with it? Please post a screen capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a empty styles for hover property. It will works after that.

```
.box {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 100px;
border: 2px solid green;
}
.box:after {
content:"";
position: absolute;
top: -6px;
left: -6px;
display: block;
width: 108px;
height: 108px;
border: 2px solid red;
display:none;
}
.box:hover{} /* This is additional */
.box:hover:after 
{
display:block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vhWgA/2/)

**NOTE:** This issue will occur only on Windows 7 IE10. Looks like a Microsoft bug. Works fine in Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to replicate this in IE10 on Windows 8.

Seems like IE10 doesn't like the hover on `div`'s (or anything that's not a link). If you change the element to an `a` (and set `display: block` on it too) it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/vhWgA/

```
<a class="box" href="#">hover me</a>
```

Of course, if you need `.box` to be a `div` then just add a link inside which deals with the hover. E.g.:

```
<div class="box"><a href="#">hover me</a><div>
```

Comment: guys i am unable to post another question. stackoverflow have too restriction. always i am geeting error like 'question does not meet bla..bla..' can u guide me what wrong i am doing.

my question is-:
    Guys in many website i saw that they use display **inline** instead of float left. 
    I use this   for my project but i am getting a little margin around the element.
    I have two question.
    1. why we use inline instead of float.. is this better options
    2. how can resolve margin without setting -4px margin.

Comment: Have a read of [CSS display: inline-Block: Why It Rocks, And Why It Sucks](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)